# how to implement tcp socket in server of client -server architecture

Tags: symbian

my problem is that ,

i have to implement tcp socket in server of client -server architecture

1)tcp ip socket is implemeted using active object

2)CTimeServer class is derieved from CServer2 which is derive from active object

both class are derive from active object and if i call cTimeserver instance and it shows EUserPanic 47 error

what is proper way to implement tcp.ip socket in Cserver2 derived server class

thanks in advance

Comment: rahulm, 

in Forum Nokia website, there are a lot of code samples, including networking implementations.
Take a look at http://migre.me/bwKm

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bad idea to use the CServer2 derived object to handle the RSocket asynchronous functions. 
Create separate active objects (usually one for readin and one for writing) for the sockets.